# Laravel Extend Token TTL

Tags: laravel, jwt, ttl

I'm trying to extend token expiration before it ends on certain conditions.
I'm using the payload to get the current expiration.

```
$payload = JWTAuth::parseToken()->getPayload();
$expires_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $payload->get('exp'));
```

How can I extend this 'exp' without changing the token.

Comment: You could set the `jwt.ttl` config on runtime, before generating the token with: `config(['jwt.ttl' => 60])`. But normally you use te refresh token to get a fresh auth token at the client side to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can change with file .env

```
JWT_TTL={minute}
JWT_REFRESH_TTL={minute}
```

Comment: I need to change it only if its about to expire , not before set

Comment: When it's expired, the client can use the `reftesh_token` to grep a new jwt token, without having to give credentials. Why not use the protocol?

Comment: @SirMissAlot
I have edited the answer, you can change the time to suit your project.

Comment: I need to extend the expiration without changing the token Or reloading @Daantje

Comment: @Beater Does the refresh return new token ?

Comment: You can't change the expire ttl after the token is generated, because the expire ttl is part of the token. That is the whole idea of JWT.

Comment: You have to write an api refresh token, and call it before it expires.

Comment: @SirMissAlot This is how it works: Use the access token to make your requests. When this one expires, just then you use the refresh token. This one should return a new access token (with new refresh token optionally) which you can continue working until it expires again, and this keeps repeating. If the refresh token is no longer valid, just then you need to re-login the user (to get fresh access & refresh tokens).

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll check this changes